# Force quit AppleScript application on error condition

Tags: shell, applescript

```
try
    set logindetails to (do shell script "curl google.com")
    on error
        display dialog "Unable to connect."
        quit
end try
```

When I put my network down, it gives me an error saying "unable to resolve host" and it never quits the application rather it stays in the background.

Is there a proper way to quit the application when unable to connect to the server or any other command to **force quit** or suppress and continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to end a running script is to use `return`:

```
try
  set logindetails to (do shell script "curl google.com")
on error
  display dialog "Unable to connect."
  return
end try
```

See the [AppleScript Language Guide’s pertinent section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH7g-163937).

Comment: I did use return but the application doesn't quit. It remains in the background. I tried with on idle as my application continually runs in the bckgrd and also tried without on idle. It does work. 

It basically doesn't quit because it looks for the unresolved host and never completes the task which it needs to quit.
Any other solution?

Comment: Is `curl` actually returning? Try adding `--max-time 15` to the `curl` command to time out the connection after 15 sec.

Comment: `curl` is getting stuck at this point waiting for the response and the application gets stuck here. I then have to force quit. I want to continue at this point when the connection with server breaks.
I tried `--max-time 15` but it doesn't after a succesful connection and then when connection breaks and this app runs in the background with `on idle`.

Comment: You might be able to alleviate the issue but wrapping the `set` command in a `with timeout` block – however, it would be much easier to find a solution if you posted your actual code (I’m guessing you are not actually polling Google for login credentials); just obfuscate sensitive data like passwords or such, please.

Comment: It worked for me when I used `-max -time` interval.
                                                                     `curl --max-time 5 -d \"username=" & loginusername & " \" " & domain & "/playlists.php`. Yes i was not using google to pull data. This line of code is the real code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use `error number -128`:

```
try
  set logindetails to (do shell script "curl google.com")
on error
  display dialog "Unable to connect."
  error number -128
end try
```

Comment: What is this code going to do? I want to avoid error dialog box to appear. I will try this out though.

Comment: Exact same thing as calling `return` – actually, that is the error code the script returns with when you call call `return`:).